# CakePHP - the SQL log shows a working query which returns a row, but results variable is NULL?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

So, here's my controller code:

```
public function admin_index(){
    $clients = $this->paginate();
    $this->set(compact('clients'));
}
```

And here's the relevant query from my SQL dump for this page:

```
SELECT `Client`.`id`, `Client`.`user_id`, `Client`.`first_name`, `Client`.`last_name`, `Client`.`company`, `Client`.`phone`, `Client`.`created`, `Client`.`modified`, (IF(LENGTH(company) > 0,company,CONCAT(first_name," ",last_name))) AS `Client__name` FROM `clients` AS `Client` WHERE 1 = 1 LIMIT 20
```

This query returns 1 row (under *Num rows*, 1 is displayed, just to be clear :).

In the view (or the controller), var_dump($clients) gives NULL

I can't understand why that is happening!

Comment: do a `debug($clients); exit;` before `$this->set(compact('clients'));` - do you get the expected output?

Comment: @Ross - nope, there's nothing in the variable.  It's not an empty array, though, which I believe a query with no results should be, it's actually null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I feel like a bit of a chump...

The offending code was actually in the model file, client.php.

```
public function afterFind(){
    //todo
}
```

I was planning on writing some code here, but neglected to.  afterFind needs to return an array of results.  I wasn't doing so, hence all calls to Client::find (ie via ClientsController::paginate) were returning NULL, not even an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller change:

```
$this->set(compact('clients'));
```

for

```
$this->set('clients', compact('clients'));
```

Because if not the variable in the view has no name, so you can't access it.

Comment: `$this->set( compact( 'clients' ) );` is perfectly valid. `$this->set( 'clients', compact( 'clients' ) );` would set the value of `$clients` in the view to `array( $clients );`.

Comment: Actually, to `array( 'clients' => $clients )`, but the point still stands.

Comment: Ah I see, guess I'm just used to doing it that way, thanks for the correction.